# should there be a semicolon at the end of do-while(0) macro?

Tags: c

I can see the `do{}while(0)` guard MACRO being extensively used and while some cases it is defined with a `;` at the end where as some are defined without a `;`

Which one is more correct with `;` or without it

```
#define FOO(x)      \  
do {                \   
     if( x > 0 )    \
          bar(x);   \
     else           \
          done(x);  \
 }while(0);
```

or

```
#define FOO(x)      \  
do {                \   
     if( x > 0 )    \
          bar(x);   \
     else           \
          done(x);  \
 }while(0)
```

Comment: in that case you could avoid the do/while by omitting the last ";" after `done(x)`

Comment: @EdHeal It may be more unreadable, but is safer (without the semicolon on the end). A possible alternative is to replace the macros with static inline functions where possible.